# Animations no longer work when I hide a ProgressBar

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar

long time listener, first time caller...

I am creating a splash screen derived from Activity called SplashBase that is placed inside a shared project. The layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/linlytSplash"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imgvwSplash"
      android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ></ImageView>

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linlytProgress"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
   >
      <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progbarProgress"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      ></ProgressBar>
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtvwProgress"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:text="@string/loading_ellipsis"
         android:textStyle="bold"
      ></TextView>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am loading the animations like this :

```
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splashscreen_anim);
  animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Advance to the next screen.
        if (null != m_intentToLaunch) {
           startActivity(m_intentToLaunch);
        }

        finish();
     }
  });

  animation.setStartTime(AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() + 1000);
```

I have a derived class called Splash which lives in my main project.

I've had this splash screen for a long time now, the animation has always worked.  My ImageView is shown for 2 seconds, and then animates and disappears before calling finish() and loading the next Activity.

I am now adding a ProgressBar which only be shown for the first second (not exactly, but it's clearer if I explain it that way).  For some reason, after I hide the ProgressBar, the animation no longer works on the ImageView. When I call

```
findViewById(R.id.linlytProgress).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

the animation no longer works.  In order to test I have placed the following calls:

```
findViewById(R.id.txtvwProgress).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and then

```
findViewById(R.id.progbarProgress).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

When I hide only the TextView, things work as expected.  When I hide the ProgressBar, boom, my ImageView no longer animates.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: How are you doing the animations? Are they custom animations?

Comment: I have added that information to the question.

Comment: What is the animation doing? Could we see the code for that?

Comment: Sure, but that's another 62 lines of code. First time here, how do you propose I proceed? Just add it to the question, post it here in the comment, pastebin?

Comment: I'm not sure. Pastebin is always a good option. Not sure if seeing it will help but it's worth taking a look at. Nothing obvious in the stuff you've posted so far. Very strange :/

Comment: Yes, very strange indeed. Here's the pastebin for the animation XML: [link](http://pastebin.com/QVdELDfw )

Comment: I created a project using your snippets here, along with the pastebin of the animation, and everything works fine for me. I added findViewById(R.id.imgvwSplash).setAnimation(animation); which was missing from your snippets, but I assume is in your project or else it would never work. My projects (both library and main project) were setup as a targetSdkVersion="12" minSdkVersion="3" on the latest ADT in Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own question.  The view needed to be invalidated.

```
findViewById(R.id.imgvwSplash).invalidate();
```

et voila! It works exactly as expected, and so far on every platform that I tried it on.

Thanks to everyone who took a look at the question.

-I_Artist

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug to me. Create a sample project that reproduces the error and file a bug with that sample project on http://b.android.com. Be sure to mention on the bug where you're seeing this (particular hardware or emulator version). If you think of it, add a comment to this answer with a link to the bug report.